# jquery - change CSS of element based on its index

Tags: jquery, indexing

Does anyone know why this jquery might not work?

Ultimately I will replace the "1" index with a variable but I can't even get this working at the moment.

```
$('.myClicker').click(function() {

    $("#selectBoxContainer img").css({"background-color":"#FFF"});
    $("#selectBoxContainer img:eg(1)").css({"background-color":"#000"});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `eq()`, not `eg()`. Also, I usually use another `css()` syntax, not sure if your will work. Try this:

```
$("#selectBoxContainer img:eq(1)").css('background-color', '#000');
```

1 will be the second element, 0 is the first.

Comment: .css() syntax seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need [the eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), not eg

Answer (score 2):

All the previous answers regarding the misnamed `eq` are correct. As some additional info for you, if you are really using a variable for the index number you might find it easier using the `eq` method instead of string concatenating the selector.

This is always easier IMO:

```
var index = 1;
$("#selectBoxContainer img").eq(index).css({"background-color":"#000"});
```

Than this:

```
var index = 1;
$("#selectBoxContainer img:eq(" + index + ")").css({"background-color":"#000"});
```